# Item Query From Table and Send It To Procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

**Note**
I want to query page item name and send the corresponding items value into a procedure. I can get the item name but couldn't get the value of it. At first I use the following code:

```
    begin
     for j in (select item_name from UTLITMINF where service_id ='abc' ) loop
                val := val || ':' || j.item_name;   --items name
             END LOOP;
    /* exe := ' begin 

             dynamic_api_call(p_service => :ser,
                     p_par => :v_val,     --items value to need to send
                     o_result_json => :v_l_response_text);
            end; ';
     execute immediate exe 
             using  IN ser,
                     in  val,
                   out l_response_text;*/

     begin
         dynamic_api_call(p_service => 'abc',
                     p_par => val,     --items name from page queried from table and send its value to procedure
                     o_result_json => l_response_text);
    end;


    raise_application_error(-20001,l_response_text);
end;
```

In val parameter it contains P11_CUSTOMER. But the value of it did not pass through the procedure. How can I get the value of it? Suggest me if i need to improve my code.

Comment: Why are you using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE? Your code is not dynamic enough to require that (from what I can tell). Just put the call to `dynamic_api_call` in as usual. Rather than bind variables, just pass `ser`, `val`, and `l_response_text`.

Comment: I am trying different ways but I failed to come up with the solution that's why my last thought is to try with EXECUTE IMMEDIATE. At first I tried with the conventional way. It gives me the same error. I can only pass the item name rather than it's allocated value from the page.

Comment: Please fix the code in the question so that EXECUTE IMMEDIATE doesn't distract from the question. Why are you going into a loop to get item names? I assume you need only one item name, why not do a `select into`?

Comment: I just edited the question. Firstly I am trying with 1 item. After being successful I will add more items. That's why I included the loop. Just try to imagine with select into statement but the outcome of both of queries are same.

Comment: Did you review my answer below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `V` (short for value) and `NV` (short for numeric value) function for dynamic item names. Try something like this (you'll need to adjust on your end).

```
declare

  l_response_text varchar2(255);
  l_ser           varchar2(255) := 'abc';
  l_item_name     varchar2(255);

begin

  select item_name
  into l_item_name
  from UTLITMINF 
  where service_id = l_ser;

  dynamic_api_call(
    p_service     => l_ser,
    p_par         => v(l_item_name),
    o_result_json => l_response_text
  );

end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the dynamic sql like the below

```
   begin
 for j in (select item_name from UTLITMINF where service_id ='abc' ) loop
            val := val || ':' || j.item_name;   --items name
         END LOOP;
 exe := ' begin 

         dynamic_api_call(p_service => :ser,
                 p_par => :v_val,     --items value to need to send
                 o_result_json => :v_l_response_text);
        end ;';
 execute immediate exe 
         using ser,
                 val,
                OUT l_response_text;


raise_application_error(-20001,l_response_text);
```

Comment: the solution you mentioned return an error with end of file.. the error is "ORA-06550: line 6, column 16: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following: ; <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> The symbol ";" was substituted for "end-of-file" to continue."

Comment: i have modified the program try my latest example